# Find out related images

Tags: android, kotlin, image-processing, related-content

I am looking for the way to get related images like Pinterest search. I have searched a lot. Most of the solution is to compare image pixel by pixel something like this. What I want is to compare the image if comparing result is more than 75% I want to show the images.

Is there any algorithm or image processing library available for Android to achieve this?

Please help to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: What do you call "related" ? Pixel-by-pixel comparison only makes sense for untouched, unscaled, uncropped... images.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's why i dont want to compare pixel by pixel. I want compare the content of the image if it contains in any image.

Comment: I am not sure you understood my comment. Can you show sample images ?